# chrome extension all of a sudden not working anymore during development

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Very strange. I'm working on a chrome extension for weeks now when all of a sudden, out of nowhere it does not work anymore. I was just adding a console.log output to debug a minor issue in the popup.js when suddenly nothing worked anymore.

- No more console-outputs from the background.js which usually produced half a page of outputs on restart independently of any popup.js. The very first line of my background.js is a `console.log('background.js started');` Even this doesn't show up anymore and I didn't touch the background.js at the time this happened.
- The icon in the toolbar is still there.
- The extension is visible in the extension-manager and activated.
- The popup does not appear anymore after a click on the icon so I can't debug it.
- All the tabs in the developer tools (Elements, Console, Sources, ...) that are typically crowded with some content are vided and empty.

So this is, what I have tried to get my extension to work again:

1. Undo the last changes (even if it was just adding a console.log()
2. Reload the extension.
3. Deactivate the extension and reactivate it.
4. Uninstall the extension and reinstall it.
5. Uninstall the extension, restart Chrome, and reinstall it.
6. Uninstall the extension, restart Computer and reinstall it.
7. Checking for properly closed parentheses and things like that in all the code I've recently touched.

I tried all these several times without success. My extension still refuses to work.

I did NOT do any changes in the manifest.json which worked perfectly before.

Any ideas?

- are there maybe any shortcuts that switch the Chrome developer-mode to pause or whatever? Maybe I have by chance activated something like that?
- is there a restriction to code lines for extensions or something like that? (But I have undone all my last changes in the code)
- is my extension may be causing a stack overflow and how could I track this? (but it worked perfectly until 2h ago, I restarted Chrome and even the Computer)
- anyone had a similar experience?
- wtf is happening here? Any ideas? How would you proceed?

Comment: Does it work on a new Chrome profile?

Comment: Ok. I just loaded an elder backup of the extension and this worked. So no hidden pause-mode of the developer-mode in chrome.

Comment: @AKX: YES it works under another Chrome profile. Had to create one. But there it works.

Comment: The newer version too, that wouldn't work originally? In that case I'd say there's something wrong with your profile, unfortunately, and it might be hard to tell what exactly. :/

Comment: If you have git history then use git bisect. Otherwise use divide-and-conquer debugging: remove parts of the extensions until it starts to work then bring those parts back and see when it fails. The underlying reason could be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @AKX: Yes the newer version that doesn't work in my original profile works again in the new profile.

Comment: @wOxxOm: That's what I would have done next, but as AKX has pointed out, it seems to be not a problem of my code but maybe of my profile. Hm  ...

Comment: If you can find files related to the extension in your old profile (maybe via its extension ID string), you could try clearing those out... but it's maybe bit of a long shot.

Comment: @AKX: where and how would I search for such files in my old profile? On my computer or in my browser?

Comment: In your computer, e.g. %LOCALAPPDATA%/Google/Chrome on Windows – see e.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/

Comment: @AKX ok. I'll give it a try. But for the moment can also live with my newly created developer account. :-) I would like to rate your answers, but can't as they are just comments. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(To answer-ify my comments:)

Since we established that the new version works in a new Chrome profile, this sounds like some sort of corruption or problem in the Chrome profile.

You can try weeding out data related to the extension by scouring the old profile folder (when Chrome is not running!) - see https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/ for tips to how to find the folder.

Comment: Finally it was just erasing browser data.  Arghh! Why do I always forget about that?!